# Using functions withing variable string declaration

Tags: php, wordpress

today i'm create this function below to show some post information about user, date, post views, comments and etc.. but when i call functions within other files get me errors say `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\wamp\www\ype\wp-content\themes\yallanpe\functions.php on line 118` please how i can correct the this error

```
<?php
function YPE_show_post_info(
$post_user,
$post_tags,
$post_date,
$post_views,
$post_comments
) {

$post_user     = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-admin-users"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.the_author_posts_link();.'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$post_tags     = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-tag"></span>'.the_category('&nbsp; / &nbsp;');.'';
$post_date     = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-calendar-alt"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.get_the_date(get_option('date_format'));.'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$post_views    = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-visibility"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.getPostViews(get_the_ID());.'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$post_comments = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-admin-comments"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.comments_number('0','1','%');.'';
?>
<p class="text-muted">
    <?php 
        echo $post_user;
        echo $post_tags;
        echo $post_date;
        echo $post_views;
        echo $post_comments;
    ?>
</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Which one is line 118 ?

Comment: `$post_user` in line 118 i think the errors occure when i used functions within string but i don't know how correct these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its for bidden to make a `.` after a `;`

Try this code:

```
<?php
function YPE_show_post_info(
$post_user,
$post_tags,
$post_date,
$post_views,
$post_comments
) {

$post_user     = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-admin-users"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.the_author_posts_link().'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$post_tags     = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-tag"></span>'.the_category('&nbsp; / &nbsp;').'';
$post_date     = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-calendar-alt"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.get_the_date(get_option('date_format')).'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$post_views    = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-visibility"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.getPostViews(get_the_ID()).'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$post_comments = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-admin-comments"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.comments_number('0','1','%').'';
?>
<p class="text-muted">
    <?php 
        echo $post_user;
        echo $post_tags;
        echo $post_date;
        echo $post_views;
        echo $post_comments;
    ?>
</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you now working with me